# OData errors | context.svc/contextMaps() issue

Tags: dxa, sdl-tridion, sites-9, odata

In the application logs we see a lots of the below error printed:
Can you please let us know from where do these requests of context.svc are originating and what all does ContextMaps() method call is doing here ?

> com.sdl.odata.client.api.exception.ODataClientHttpError: Unable to get response from OData service: <metadata:error xmlns:metadata="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/metadata">metadata:code1000</metadata:code>metadata:messageInput doesn't match filter: None. uri: [http://content.abc.com/brands/context/context.svc/ContextMaps('%5B%7B%22key%22:%22user-agent%22,%22value%22:%22Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/108.0.0.0+Safari/537.36+Edg/108.0.1418.42'%22,%22origin%22:%22http%22%7D%5D')](http://content.abc.com/brands/context/context.svc/ContextMaps(%27%5B%7B%22key%22:%22user-agent%22,%22value%22:%22Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/108.0.0.0+Safari/537.36+Edg/108.0.1418.42%27%22,%22origin%22:%22http%22%7D%5D%27))</metadata:message></metadata:error>

Also, for Odata I need help identify the meaning of Error Codes. Odata mentions error code as 1000 and in some cases 9000. Where can I read about (any documentation) that gives full details on the error codes used by OData service ?

Comment: Looking at the URL, the problem seems to be with the Context Service. Maybe the Context Service logs provide more details about the error?

Comment: sure Rick, will check now and update here if I see anything